# Is this prototype GUI even possible at all in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Sirs,

As an exercise to learn more about class and function accessibility (e.g. public, private, static, etc), I am wanting to write a Java GUI (in the Netbeans IDE) that has the following properties:

1. has only one jButton and one jTextField - no other GUI components.
2. pressing the jButton for the first time after launching the program
   displays a "0" in the jTextField.
3. pressing the jButton again
   increments the number in the jTextField by one (i.e. the jButton
   plays the role of an    incrementer).
4. The jButton cannot get the
   existing text from the jTextField, read/parse the text, get the most
   recent number, and then increment    the number.

   For example:

```
String someString = jTextField.getText();
int someInt = String.valueOf(someString);
someInt++;
String newString = new String();
newString = String.valueOf(someInt);
jTextField.setText()
```

is not allowed.

This project is much more difficult than it appears, given the requirements above.  Based on the requirements, I am going to have to create a class somewhere else that can keep track of the counter value (remember, extracting the current counter value from the TextField is prohibited).  However, since Netbeans seems to disallow calling class methods of objects that were instantiated elsewhere (outside the button), this seems impossible.

After all attempts, it seems that a GUI that meets the above 4 criterion is impossible in Netbeans, given its restrictions.

My best-failed-attempt-thus-far (if that makes any sense) goes like this:

```
private void IncrementButtonActionPerformed(...){
    CountObject C = new CountObject();
    int i = C.IncrementCounter();// CountObject has a method for this.
    // line or two here to typecast i into a String
    jTextField.setText("i");
```

However, this won't work because each time I re-press the IncrementButton, it will simply instantiate a new CountObject.  Instantiating a CountObject outside of this IncrementButtonActionPerformed event handler and then calling the CountObject.IncrementCounter() method from within the event handler is disallowed, or so it seems.

So am I right in believing that the requirements 1-4 above simply cannot be done in Java Netbeans as stated?

Thanks,
the_photon

Comment: `"Please, no red-herring answers such as "eveything is possible in Java" or "try harder"."` -- if you don't like an answer, simply down-vote it. But in general, you don't want to place stipulations on any answers you might receive from a **volunteer** help site. Make sense?

Comment: Also fyi, there is no such language as "Java NetBeans". NetBeans is simply an IDE that can be used to create Java programs, and other language programs as well.

Comment: Please clarify, because this doesn't seem true: `"Java Netbeans event driven paradigm seems to disallow calling class methods of objects that were instantiated elsewhere (outside the button), this seems impossible."`

Comment: Add a int field to your class. Increment it in the actionPerformed method, then turn it to a STring and set the textfield text. I don't see why that would be impossible in Netbeans. Netbeans lets you write Java code like any other IDE.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels -  I certainly agree that Java Netbeans it not a language.  However, when I ask questions and I do not specify that I'm trying to create a GUI in Java using Netbeans, I get a bunch of responses that include code that can't be written using Netbeans, given its additional rules about what can and cannot be changed.  I'm not sure how to go about specifying that I'm using Netbeans to do all this.

Comment: @the_photon That is only when you are using the [NetBeans Gui builder](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html).

Comment: But even with the GUI builder, there's nothing stopping a coder from adding methods to the class. There really are none of the restrictions that he mentions.

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a counter int field and increment it in your button's ActionListener -- no need to get the text from the JTextField. Then the JTextField's text with the counter's value.  Edit: actually with your requirements, do the reverse: set the JTextFields text with the current counter's value and then increment the counter.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleGui extends JPanel {
    private int counter = 0;
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(5);
    private JButton incrementButton = new JButton(new IncrementAction("Increment", KeyEvent.VK_I));

    public SimpleGui() {
        textField.setFocusable(false);
        add(textField);
        add(incrementButton);
    }

    private class IncrementAction extends AbstractAction {
        public IncrementAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            counter++;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleGui mainPanel = new SimpleGui();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleGui");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks!